# I want to create a simple python program that launches google chrome and types a website's address, but the program is just stuck at google-chrome

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome

I used following code to try to create the program but it is not working

```
import pyautogui as p
import os
import time
os.system("google-chrome")
p.typewrite("website")
p.press('enter')
```

but after i execute this the program is stuck at google-chrome and it only goes to next command if i close google-chrome. Is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to navigate to a web page using Python, you may use the [`webbrowser` module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/webbrowser.html):

```py
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("your-website-here")
```